# react-sortable-hoc List disappears when I drag an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, higher-order-components, react-sortable-hoc

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/40vpaLj5/

I googled some issues and the only disappearing related issues I found were when people used it on a modal and they talked about setting the z-index to fix it.  i tried it anyway still nothing.  How can I fix this?

```
import React from 'react';
import PlaylistPages from './PlaylistPages';

class PlaylistSortableComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      test: [
        '1','2', '3', '4'
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PlaylistPages pages={this.state.test} style={{zIndex: 999999}} />
    );
  }
}   


const PlaylistPages = SortableContainer(({pages}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        pages.map((page, index) =>
          <PlaylistPage key={index} page={page} style={{zIndex: 99999999}} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
});   

const PlaylistPage = SortableElement(({page}) => {
  return (
    <div style={{zIndex: 99999999}} >{page}</div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every `sortableElement` should have it's own `index` prop:

```
<PlaylistPage key={index} index={index} page={page} style={{zIndex: 99999999}} />
```

Here is the update to your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/40vpaLj5/1/

Comment: i love you ty so much.  been banging my head for hours now

Comment: This simple thing that I missed was also driving me nuts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and **Dekel** is right. In my case the z-index fix the error:

```
<SortableList
    axis="y"
    helperClass="sortable-list-tab"
    lockAxis="y"
    distance={0}
    onSortEnd={onSortEnd}
>
    <ul>
       {toolItems.map((value, index) => (
          <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index}>
              <li className="sortable-list-tab" >
                 <Button type="dashed">{`${value.label} (${index + 1})`}</Button>
              </li>
          </SortableItem>
        ))}
    </ul>
</SortableList>
```

And the sortable-list-tab class look like:

```
.sortable-list-tab {
    cursor: default;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 99999999;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: .3em;
  }
```